# JQuery DataTables Plugin Empty Table

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I have code that builds out a table in HTML. We use fields to apply custom searches and update the table. I want to add pagination and column sorting/filtering to the table so I am trying to convert it to a jQuery datatable use the plugin from datatables.net.

I've tried creating the table and then initializing it with the .DataTable() method to no avail (doesn't add the extra features).

I've tried initializing using the data and column attributes and my table is just empty.

I've tried following the below documentation:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/ - I was able to get the samples here to work but I am using a different type for the data source and a newer version of the libraries
- https://datatables.net/manual/data/ - The actual documentation showing how to properly use my data source with the newer version (can't get this to work)
- Several questions on stackoverflow

And my jQuery datatable displays an empty table with no errors in the developer console.

table:

```
<table id="productsearchresults">
    <thead>
        <tr id="header">
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Unit Price
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Relevant javascript:

```
var recordData = j$.map(data.records, function(item) {
    return {
        name: item.Name,
        description: item.Product2.Description,
        unitprice: item.UnitPrice
    };
});

var columns = [
    {data:'name'},
    {data:'description'},
    {data:'unitprice'}
];

console.log(recordData);
console.log(columns);

j$('#productsearchresults').DataTable({
    data: recordData,
    columns: columns
});
```

Console Output:

[image: console output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. I tried to replicate the issue by using the same code as  yours but it is working for me.

**JS**

```
var recordData = [
    {name:'Item A', description:'Description 1', unitprice:'12.36'},
    {name:'Item B', description:'Description 2', unitprice:'63.98'},
    {name:'Item C', description:'Description 3', unitprice:'1258.99'}];

var columns = [
    {data:'name'},
    {data:'description'},
    {data:'unitprice'}
];

  $('#productsearchresults').DataTable({
    data: recordData,
    columns: columns
  });
```

See it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvaJVW?editors=1010

Can you make sure you included the jQuery before the datatables js?

Comment: I did, I've been using jquery on the page for all sorts of other stuff.

Comment: I copied your code and I get a stylized table with no data :( I copied it into my blank test page to help make sure no conflicts or anything.

Comment: I was able to get your to work in my test page by using the most recent version of all of the libraries, I'm going to check my scripts to make sure they are up to date

Comment: My jquery was not using the most recent version